# inner Join or self query

Tags: self

I have a table with 3 columns

column 1 called URI with values :  1,2,3,4,5,6,
Column 2 called record type with values :  box, folder, box, folder, item, folder 
Column 3 called parent URI with values : 0,2,0,4,4,1

Basically the table has information  about record number ( uri),what it is ? a box, folder or item ( record type) , and the URI of its container ( parent uri)

so  ideally an item  should exist in a folder and a folder in a box. and there
cases where a record is orphan

Need to write a query that can show in perhaps 4 columns

uri, record type, parent uri, and parent uri record type

I think it can be done because  a row like

3,box, 5 means record number 3 is a box and  its parent is 5. there will exist
another row that will have 5 as a uri , its record type and its parent.

Help regards

Comment: You should add which database system you are using. You could improve the question further by formating the sample data as tables. I can not really understand what you are asking.

Comment: I am using SQL 2008                                                                                             g

Comment: not sure how to format a table here but have 3 colums and table 1 and 3 have common values. need to populate or create a 4 the column that fills that column with 2nd column value where ever 1 and 3 are the same